# Cannot do the First Time Install of Cognos when Windows unexpectedly restarted

Tags: cognos

I was in the middle of installing Cognos Server (First time install) when Windows 10 unexpectedly restarted. Now, there is a cognos folder in the installation directory but I cannot uninstall it or delete it.

**Using the Uninstall option in the cognos folder produces the following error:**

This Application has Unexpectedly Quit
Invocation of this Java Application has caused an Invocation TargetException. This application will now exit (LAX)

**If I try to delete the cognos folder:**
It says that some folder/file is open in another program. I have stopped all IBM and ApacheDS-cognos services. But still get this error while manually deleting the cognos folder.

What can I do to fix this and do the 'First Time Install' of cognos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you did an Easy Install, then you should also check for Informix services running, stop them and then re-try deleting the folder.  Check for processes running like cogbootstrap.exe and kill them, as well as any other processes running in that install directory and any JVMs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The folders are deleted now, but the installation still does not let me do First Install. I see the error `"First Install" installation is not allowed`. Is there any other way to reset it?

Comment: I had to additionally delete the Informix registry entries and delete the Informix user account. Now, I can do First Install.